# Modelling optional one to many relationship - should I use inheritance?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to model a weather service that supports multiple locations. My application has 3 entities:

1. Location - information about the Location
2. Weather (includes location id) - A single hour of weather data
3. LocationWeather - Subclass of Location containing a List of Weather

I want Location to sometimes exist as a distinct entity from Weather. That way I can expose CRUD operations on the Location object without carrying the bloat of all of its weather data. However, I still want to satisfy the primary use case of returning weather for a given location, that's why LocationWeather exists.

Can what I want to do be done with inheritance? I've tried

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="location")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Location {
```

but my subclass (LocationWeather) doesn't directly associate with a table. Should I move my List of Weather up to the Location object and somehow mark it as optional?

**Location.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="location")
public class Location {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="location_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
```

**Weather.java**

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(WeatherId.class)
@Table(name="weather")
public class Weather {

    @Id
    @Column(name="location_id")
    private int locationId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="time")
    private Date time;

    @Column(name="temperature")
    private Double temperature;
```

**LocationWeather.java**

```java
@Entity
public class LocationWeather extends Location{

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="weather", joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="location_id")})
    @Column(name="weather")
    private List<Weather> weather;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was googling the wrong things. I should have been searching for "2 entities 1 table"

I was able to solve the issue by creating a @MappedSuperclass and creating Location and LocationWeather as a subclass of it.

Now I have:

**MappedLocation.java**

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class MappedLocation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="location_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
```

**Location.java**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="location")
public class Location extends MappedLocation {

}
```

**LocationWeather.java**

```java
@Entity
public class LocationWeather extends MappedLocation{

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="weather", joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="location_id")})
    @Column(name="weather")
    private List<Weather> weather;
```

More info: https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-multiple-entities-same-table/